# ipython notebook doesn't work: OSError: [Errno None not found] 2

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, miniconda

I follow instruction and run ipython.exe notebook:

```
> [TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand `ipython notebook` is
> deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
> [TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | You likely want to use `jupyter
> notebook` in the future Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Miniconda3\Scripts\ipython-script.py", line 5, in <module>
>     sys.exit(IPython.start_ipython())   File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 119, in
> start_ipython
>     return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)   File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
> line 657, in launch_instance
>     app.initialize(argv)   File "<decorator-gen-110>", line 2, in initialize   File
> "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
> line 87, in catch_config_error
>     return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 300,
> in initialize
>     super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)   File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize   File
> "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
> line 87, in catch_config_error
>     return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line
> 446, in initialize
>     self.parse_command_line(argv)   File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 295,
> in parse_command_line
>     return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)   File "<decorator-gen-4>", line 2, in parse_command_line   File
> "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
> line 87, in catch_config_error
>     return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
> line 514, in parse_command_line
>     return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)   File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line
> 236, in initialize_subcommand
>     return super(BaseIPythonApplication, self).initialize_subcommand(subc, argv)   File "<decorator-gen-3>",
> line 2, in initialize_subcommand   File
> "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
> line 87, in catch_config_error
>     return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
> line 445, in initialize_subcommand
>     subapp = import_item(subapp)   File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\ipython_genutils\importstring.py",
> line 31, in import_item
>     module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj]) ImportError: No module named 'notebook'
```

Now if I run jupyter notebook, I get:

> C:\Miniconda3\Scripts>jupyter notebook Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "C:\Miniconda3\Scripts\jupyter-script.py", line 5, in
>   
>       sys.exit(jupyter_core.command.main())   File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 186,
>   in main
>       _execvp(command, sys.argv[1:])   File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 104,
>   in _execvp
>       raise OSError('%r not found' % cmd, errno.ENOENT) OSError: [Errno None not found] 2

I need to save my work as ipython notebook. How can I do it?

Comment: This is _not your fault_.  You have an incomplete or mangled installation.  Also, Jupyter Inc. has neglected the First Law of Backwards Incompatible Changes (namely "Don't") and that means your tutorial is inaccurate.  Unfortunately I do not know where to get either a good installation or an up-to-date tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like `zwol` said, your installation might have gotten screwed up.  There are two things you can do.

1. Completely remove your miniconda installation and try again.
2. Create a new environment and install ipython/jupyter there.  I would try this first.

   `conda create -n myenv python=3

   activate myenv

   conda install jupyter

   jupyter notebook`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, but I created a 'testenv' and run the jupyter notebook there and it worked for me.
Something got screwed on the main install but you can install work in a different environment.